# vba code to compare two ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have two ranges that I compare to find the values that does not compare. These values need to be pasted in new cells. The code I have works perfect but for some reason it will not work if the cell values are numbers only.

Please see below.

```
Sub RangeCompare2()

Dim Rg1 As Range, Rg2 As Range, c1 As Range, rgPaste2 As Range
Dim lngRowOffset3 As Long

On Error Resume Next

lngRowOffset3 = 0
Set Rg1 = Worksheets("Bridget Madumo").Range("AQ40:AQ70")
Set Rg2 = Worksheets("Bridget Madumo").Range("C69:C122")
Set rgPaste2 = Worksheets("BM CS").Range("C102")
Set rgPaste2 = rgPaste2.Cells(1, 1)

On Error GoTo 0

For Each c1 In Rg1.Cells

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rg2, c1.Value & "*") = 0 Then

    rgPaste2.Offset(lngRowOffset3).Value = c1.Value
    rgPaste2.Offset(lngRowOffset3, 1).Value = c1.Offset(, 1).Value
    rgPaste2.Offset(lngRowOffset3, 2).Value = c1.Offset(, 2).Value
    rgPaste2.Offset(lngRowOffset3, 3).Value = c1.Offset(, 3).Value
    lngRowOffset3 = lngRowOffset3 + 1
    End If

Next c1

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: `c1.Value & "*"` turns it into a text string and countif will not find a match of a text string with a number.  Load both ranges into memory array and  loop the arrays and compare.  That way you can turn both into text strings and compare using `Like`

Comment: Hi Scott. Thank you for the great explenation. I am not great at vba. Will it be possible for you to explain to me how to load the ranges into memory array and loop through to only be left with the values that do not match?